# Need help about a longitudinal study with eye tracking data

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I am currently conducting a longitudinal research on learner reading development in second language. Let me explain it briefly. I am using eye tracking procedures and trying to describe the development of reading skills of my participants. Saccade lenght (how fast they read), fixation durations (how long they look at the text) and regressions (how many times they return and read again) are my main variables which predicts their reading skill level. For example, less fixation and less regression means higher reading ability. So this is a study which will continue two semester (about 8 months) and in this period, I will conduct about 6 eye tracking sessions after classroom instruction. These 6 sessions include all the variables I mentioned above and which statistical tests should I use to describe the developments in their reading ability? Indeed this is not a pre test post test issue but rather a development in behavior. Can I apply hierarchical regression and how? What do you think? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your account I do not see any mention of actual measurements of reading ability.  How, then, do you propose to draw any conclusions about reading ability at all?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, learners will take IELTS general reading exam before each eye tracking session. So, I want to find out which factors (saccade length, fixations and regressions) influence their scores and development. For instance; a participant scoring 22 will have an eye tracking session aftermath. Then I want to find out which factors affect this score and what is its relationship with previous scores and factors. This score-eye tracking procedure will be employed 6 times in an academic year. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: https://sites.temple.edu/deepstat/files/2014/07/LPiTrack2016.pdf

We have developed LPiTrack, a comprehensive nonparametric statistical learning framework for large-scale eye-movement pattern discovery.

Comment: For this to be considered a complete answer, please provide the OP and other readers with key points from the link.